# Matrix multiplication properties

Tags: matrices

So I have to solve this

$$\hat\beta = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y$$

I was wondering if I can solve

$(X'Y)$ seperately and

$(X'X)^{-1}$

then combine both matrices later such that

$(X'X)^{-1}(X'Y)$?

Comment: Recall the associative property of multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it the way you said. But there is no reason to compute $(X^T X)^{-1}$ explicitly. Just solve 
$$
X^T X \beta = X^T Y
$$
using a method such as Gaussian elimination.